# Access to public variable from other contract

Tags: solidity

Unable to access to public variable in Test.sol contract from other contract. How to do it?

Test.sol contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
    uint256 public val = 256;
}
```

My attemps to access variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./Test.sol";

contract Other {

    address testAddress;

    function setAddress(address _address) {
        testAddress = _address;            
    }    

    function getVal() public returns (uint256) {
        return Test(testAddress).val;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following Code for it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
    uint256 public val = 256;
}


contract Other {

    Test testContract;

    function setAddress(address _address) {
        testContract = Test(_address);            
    }    

    function getVal() constant public returns (uint256) {
        return testContract.val();
    }
}
```

You need to define a variable which is of type `Test`. Than you can get the value of `val` by calling its getter function `val()` which is automatically generated due to the `public` keyword.

**EDIT**:

If you want to make variable `val` private and only accessible for the `Other` contract you should provide a getter function like the following:

```
function getVal() public returns (uint) {
    return val;
}
```

Now you can set the permissions for `getVal()` so that only addresses who may access `val` will have permissions to read it.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**:

This is a complete code snippet for keeping the variable `val` private and only allow `Other` contract to read it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {

    address owner;
    uint256 val = 256;
    address otherContract;

    function Test(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOtherContract() {
        require(msg.sender == otherContract);
        _;
    }

    function setOtherContract(address _otherContract) onlyOwner {
        otherContract = _otherContract;
    }

    function getVal() onlyOtherContract returns (uint) {
        return val;
    }
}


contract Other {

    Test testContract;

    function setAddress(address _address) {
        testContract = Test(_address);            
    }    

    function getVal() constant public returns (uint256) {
        return testContract.getVal();
    }
}
```

Try the following steps:

1. Deploy `Test` contract
2. Deploy `Other` contract
3. Set `testContract` in `Other` contract with the `setAddress` function
4. Set the `otherContract` variable in the `Test` contract with the `setOtherContract` function
5. Call the `getVal` function in the `Other` contract.

Now you can also try to call the `getVal` function in the `Test` contract directly and you will see, that your call is reverted. This is because after step 4 only the `Other` contract is allowed to call `getVal`.

Kind regards

Comment: I've tried to do like you, but i i get VM exception because of revert. Do you have any ideas why this revert was throwed

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope things are more clearly now...

Comment: same issue revert.

Comment: the answer seems wrong, contract cannot get public value of other contract without method