# Access contract instance from multiple contracts

Tags: solidity

My question is a variation of this one ([old question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/access-to-public-variable-from-other-contract)).

In contract **Test**, the variable *myval* is created. In contract **Other**, an instance of the **Test** contract is created, and I access the instance variable with the getter function.

However, what if I want to access the same instance from another contract, **Other2**? If I try to use the same instance name, *testContract*, an error is raised about undeclared identifier so it must be a visibility issue. I do not want to create a new instance of **Test** because at some point, the value of *myval* will change and I need to access its value from multiple contracts.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is there an easier way? Note, the structure of **Other2** will be much different than **Other**, so I don't want to just create a child and inherit the same stuff from it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
    bool public myval;
}


contract Other {

    Test public testContract;  

    function setAddress2() {
        testContract = new Test();
    }

    function getVal() constant public returns (bool) {
        return testContract.myval();
    }
}

contract Other2 {
    //what to put here?**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass address of the Test contract as a parameter in constructors of both Other and Other2 contracts. Then access myval attribute as Test(testAddress).myval

Comment: Can this pass be executed programatically instead of manually copying the `Test` address and pasting it into the `Other` constructor?

Comment: Nm, I think I figured it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the above answer:

```
contract Other2 {
 
    Test public testContract;  

    function setAddressFromOther(Other other){
        testContract = other.testContract();
    }

    function getVal() constant public returns (bool) {
        return testContract.myval();
    }   
}
```

Just submit tx which calls `setAddressFromOther(other_addr)` with the address of the `Other` contract deployed

Comment: So this works, thanks. How do you accomplish this automatically? Ideally, I don't want to fiddle around with manually copying the address of `Other` and pasting it into the `setAddressFromOther` function. I'd like to have the address ready to access within `Other2`.